# Need regex for a specific pattern

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need regex that matches the following pattern

The string must match
'/ashok/.....'
but should not match with 
'/ashok/...:...' and 
'/ashok/file:abc...'

ex: `/ashok/xyz` should match
but `/ashok/file:abc.jpg` should not.

colon should not appear after second forward slash

Comment: The colon don't appear immediately after second slash. After second forward slash there will be atleast 1 alphanumeric character. But a colon should not appear after that. For example /ashok/xyz should pass but /ashok/xyz: and /ashok/xyz:abc should not .After the colon there will be characters too. That shouldn't pass too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain that I understand what you are asking for. But you can try a negative lookahead:

```
/\/ashok\/(?!.*:).+/g
```

This will only match `/ashok/xyz` if no colons appear after the second forward slash. This regex requires that at least one non-colon character follows the second forward slash. If that's not necessary, you can use:

```
/\/ashok\/(?!.*:).*/g
```

You can read this [page](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) to learn more about negative lookaheads (and lookarounds in general).

**Edit**

Alternatively, if your subject string should contain only one instance of your construct and nothing else, you can use this to avoid lookarounds:

```
/^\/ashok\/[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

Or if you need it to match more than one forward-slash-delimited group of alphanumeric characters:

```
/^\/ashok(?:\/[a-z0-9]+)+$/i
```

Comment: The colon don't appear immediately after second slash. After second forward slash there will be atleast 1 alphanumeric character. But a colon should not appear after that. For example 
/ashok/xyz should pass 
but /ashok/xyz: and /ashok/xyz:abc should not .After the colon there will be characters too. That shouldn't pass too

Comment: Well, if that's the case, you can use `/\/ashok\/(?!.+:).+/g`. I've also added two more regex strings to my original answer that do not make use of lookarounds. If I understand your requirements, the first of those strings (`/^\/ashok\/[a-z0-9]+$/i`) is exactly what you're looking for.